# Get Unique web browser ID in PHP

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox, safari, browser

I am looking a way to store unique ID of web browsers in `PHP`? I searched everywhere..but couldn't find any useful things. First of all, does web browsers have a unique ID or something like that to identify them??? Like the computers have a unique IP address, does browsers have anything like that?? I am trying this so that I can store user details into my database. So, we can find out a user used which browser to access my `PHP` website. Can I store such an ID to a `php` variable?

for example, `$x= ID` of the web browser.

Comment: You track this kind of thing with [cookies](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Comment: Cookies are used to identify a user. I am trying to identify the browser a user uses. @Digital Chris

Comment: When you store the cookie (or unique hash) in your database, you store it along with every other information you grab from the visitor: IP, browser, OS, resolution, etc.

Comment: How secure is a cookie?? @amenadiel

Comment: Well, for a start you can only set and read cookies for your domain. You can't see what other cookies is your visitor's browser carrying around nor set cookies to impersonate facebook, for example. Your user can delete or edit the cookies in his browser, but you can store hashed strings so they won't be obvious to tamper with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a user visits your site you know his IP, browser, OS and other stuff. You need to know if the next time the same user visits you (same IP, same login perhaps) is using the same browser. This can be achieved in two ways:

a) Create a cookie, store it in the browser and in your DB, then compare every visitor that has that cookie against your existing cookie table to identify him. If the cookie has a very long expiration time it won't be lost across sessions, and will be unique to each browser. But it will be lost if the user clears cookies.

b) Store a string in the browser's local storage. This works pretty much the same as the cookie method but there's no expiration date for the data, and it's thougher to remove it than to clear cookies.

There are other methods, like combining different kind of cookies to provide redundancy. I remember [a project called Evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) that did something like that. I believe it's pretty much abandoned now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [browscap](https://browscap.org/) library and then make an md5 of the browser information:

Uses [GaretJax/phpbrowscap](https://github.com/GaretJax/phpbrowscap/wiki/QuickStart)

```
$bc = new \phpbrowscap\Browscap('data/');
$current_browser = $bc->getBrowser(null,true);
$str = json_encode($current_browser);
$browser_id = md5($str);
```